# which is the function of (3) based in this equation

Tags: functions, functional-equations, function-and-relation-composition

If we know that $(f\circ f)(x)=4x+3$, with $f(0)=4$, what is $f(3)=?$

I have found that $f(f(x))= 16x+15$, but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: This is not clear.  What's the difference between $f\circ f(x)$ and $f[f(x)]$?

Comment: I don't understand the part about $16x+5$.  For the earlier part, note that $f\circ f(0)=3\implies f(f(0))=3\implies f(4)=3\implies f\circ f(4)=f(3)$. Can you finish from there?

Comment: how did you find that f(4)=3

Comment: We know that $f(f(0))=3$ and $f(0)=4$.

Comment: so how does that help us?

Comment: Please try to work it yourself from the hint I gave.  I did it all for you but the very last step.

Comment: yeah i got it. thank you.is the correct answer 19 ?

Comment: Yes!  good work.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $f(0)=4$ and $f(f(0))=3$, so $f(4)=3$ which implies $f(3)=f(f(4))=19$.